# Rare EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION when debugging any process started with CREATE_SUSPENDED

Tags: c++, debugging, winapi

While writing an x86 WinAPI-based debugger, I've encountered a rare condition when the debuggee (which usually works well) suddenly terminates with `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION` after I attach to it with my native debugger. I can stably reproduce this on any applications it seems (tried on .NET Hello World-styled application and on `notepad.exe` on multiple Windows 10 machines).

Essentially I've written a simple `WaitForDebugEvent` loop:

```
CreateProcessW(L"C:\\Windows\\SYSWOW64\\notepad.exe", […], CREATE_SUSPENDED, […]);
DebugActiveProcess(processId);

DEBUG_EVENT debugEvent = {};
while (WaitForDebugEvent(&debugEvent, INFINITE)) {
  switch (debugEvent.dwDebugEventCode) {
    // log all the events
  }
  ContinueDebugEvent(debugEvent.dwProcessId, debugEvent.dwThreadId, DBG_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED);
}

DebugActiveProcessStop(processId);
```

([here's the full listing](https://github.com/ForNeVeR/WindowsDebuggerIssue/blob/326d32ea20e2c587c7c7592efceace03cfeedce6/NetRuntimeWaiter/NetRuntimeWaiter.cpp): I won't paste it all here, because there's some additional non-essential boilerplate there; the MCVE is 136 lines long)

For the sake of an example, I'll just log all the debugger events and detect whether the debuggee is ready to "proceed normally" or it will terminate due to an exception.

Most of the time, my debugging session looks like that:

- `CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT` (which reports creation of both the process and its initial thread)
- `LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT` (I was never able to get the name for this DLL, but this is documented in MSDN)
- `CREATE_THREAD_DEBUG_EVENT` (which, I suspect, is a thread injected by debugger)
- `LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT` […] — after this, many DLLs get loaded into the target process and everything looks okay, the process works as intended

But sometimes (in about 1.5% of all runs), the event sequence changes:

- `CREATE_PROCESS_DEBUG_EVENT`
- `LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_EVENT`
- `CREATE_THREAD_DEBUG_EVENT`
- `EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION` (which I never was able to gather details for: it reports a DEP violation, and the address is empty)

After that, I cannot proceed with debugging, because my debuggee is in exception state and will terminate soon. I was never able to catch `notepad.exe` crash without my debugger attached (and I doubt it is that bad and will crash for no reason), so I suspect that my debugger causes these exceptions.

One bizarre detail is that I could "fix" the situation by calling `Sleep(1)` immediately after `WaitForDebugEvent`. So, this is *possibly* some sort of race condition, but race condition between what? Between the debugger thread and other threads in the debuggee? Is it a thing? How are we supposed to debug other applications, then? How could actual debuggers work if it is a thing?

I couldn't reproduce the issue with the same code compiled for x64 CPU (and debugging an x64 process).

What could actually cause this erroneous behavior? I've carefully read the documentation about the API functions I call, and checked some other debugger examples online, but still wasn't able to find what's wrong with my debugger: it looks like I follow all the right conventions.

I have tried to debug my debuggee with WinDBG while it is still paused in my debugger, but had no luck doing that. First of all, it's difficult to attach to the debuggee with another debugger (WinDBG only allows to use non-intrusive mode, which is less functional it seems?), and the call stacks for the process' threads aren't usually meaningful.

### Steps to reproduce

Checkout [this repository](https://github.com/ForNeVeR/WindowsDebuggerIssue), compile with MSVC and then execute in `cmd`:

```
Debug\NetRuntimeWaiter.exe > log.txt
```

It is important to redirect output to the log file and not show it in the terminal: without that, timings for the log writer get changed, and the issue won't reproduce (due to a possible race condition I mentioned earlier?).

Usually the program will start and terminate 1000 notepads in about 10 seconds, and 10-15 of 1000 invocations will hold the error condition (i.e. `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION`).

Comment: not use `DebugActiveProcess`  api. it create thread (for what ?!) in target process. as result your process start on another thread (you suspend first). use native api - `NtDebugActiveProcess` if you try debug already running process - all will be ok, even if you call it in your example in place `DebugActiveProcess`. also if you create process yourself - not call both this api, but use flags - `DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS` or `DEBUG_PROCESS` and not use `CREATE_SUSPENDED`

Comment: I am aware of `DEBUG_PROCESS`, but unfortunately there're tricky cases in the wild, when one process I control starts the debuggee, but another process I control needs to debug the target. That's why they have to cooperate by working with a suspended debuggee.

Thanks for the `NtDebugActiveProcess` advice, I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: use in this case flag `DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS` - this is exactly what you need if i correct understand your comment. this is more correct by design. the `NtDebugActiveProcess` you need use only in case if not you create process. however `NtDebugActiveProcess` will be ok in your code instead `DebugActiveProcess` (error) but for what ?

Comment: by fact call `NtDebugActiveProcess` will be have the **same** effect as use `DEBUG_[ONLY_THIS_]PROCESS` flag. but this is extra api call, which is not need. also if use flags - you directly control - debug only this process or childs too. however you always latter can change this by call `NtSetInformationProcess` with `ProcessDebugFlags` - `PROCESS_DEBUG_INHERIT`

Comment: unlike this - the `DebugActiveProcess` and `DbgUiDebugActiveProcess` create thread in target process - and exactly this lead to your bug

Comment: *difficult to attach to the debuggee with another debugger* - but possible with good debugger :)

Comment: @RbMm, could you please write an answer about `NtDebugActiveProcess`? Looks like it works, I'd happily accept that. You could also leave a note about `DEBUG_PROCESS`: even if that's impossible to use in my case (because other process starts the debuggee in suspended state), it could be useful for others.

Comment: you need use `DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS` flag exactly. and you not need create process in suspened state (not use `CREATE_SUSPENDED`). create process with  `DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS` only flag and test. you see that this will be full ok for you

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot use `DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS`. In the real code, the process is not started from my debugger, and `DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS` only works for cases when it is. Consider that I receive an process id of the process that is already started in the suspended state, and that's all.

Comment: understand now. but i assume component which send you process id and create process - write you too ? possible the next solution here - this process need to take your process debug object (duplicate it to self process) and call `DbgUiSetThreadDebugObject (hDebug)` before call `CreateProcess` and then `DbgUiSetThreadDebugObject(0)`. as result your process just become a debug new process. get your debug object you can via `DbgUiGetThreadDebugObject ()` and create it via `DbgUiConnectToDbg()`. i assume you already use this api for `NtDebugActiveProcess`

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I'll try that, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the [`DebugActiveProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-debugactiveprocess) (and undocumented `DbgUiDebugActiveProcess` which is internally called by `DebugActiveProcess`) have serious design problem: after calling `NtDebugActiveProcess` it create remote thread in the target process, via `DbgUiIssueRemoteBreakin` call - as result new thread in target process is created - `DbgUiRemoteBreakin` - this thread call [`DbgBreakPoint`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/nf-wdm-dbgbreakpoint) and then `RtlExitUserThread`

all this not documented and explained, only this note from [`DebugActiveProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-debugactiveprocess):

> After all of this is done, the system resumes all threads in the
>   process. When the first thread in the process resumes, it executes a
>   breakpoint instruction that causes an `EXCEPTION_DEBUG_EVENT`
>   debugging event to be sent to the debugger.

of course this is wrong. why is `DbgUiRemoteBreakin` first (??) thread ? and which thread resume first undefined. why not exactly write - we create additional (but not first) thread in process ? and this thread execute breakpoint.

however, when process already running - create this additional thread not create problems. but in case we create process in suspended state, and then just call `DebugActiveProcess` - the `DbgUiRemoteBreakin` really became first executing thread in process and process initialization was done on this thread, instead of created first thread. on xp this always lead to fail process initialize at connect to csrss phase. (csrss wait connect to it only on first created thread in process). on later systems this is fixed and process can execute as usual. but can and not, because thread on which it was initialized is exit. it can cause subtle problems.

solution here - not use [`DebugActiveProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-debugactiveprocess) but `NtDebugActiveProcess` in it place.
the debug object we can create or via `DbgUiConnectToDbg()` and then get it via `DbgUiGetThreadDebugObject()` (system store debug object in thread *TEB*) or direct by call `NtCreateDebugObject`

also if we create debuggee process from another process(*B*) we can do next:

- duplicate debug object from debugger process to this *B* process
- call `DbgUiSetThreadDebugObject(hDdg)` just before call
  `CreateProcessW` with `DEBUG_ONLY_THIS_PROCESS` or `DEBUG_PROCESS`
- system will be use `DbgUiGetThreadDebugObject()` for get debug object
  from your thread and pass it to low level process create api
- remove debug object from your thread via
  `DbgUiSetThreadDebugObject(0)`

really no matter who is create process with debug object. matter who is handle events posted to this debug object.

all undocumented api definitions you can take from [*ntdbg.h*](https://processhacker.sourceforge.io/doc/ntdbg_8h_source.html) and then link with *ntdll.lib* or *ntdllp.lib*